# upload Rest API Dropbox using ajax

Tags: ajax, rest, file-upload, dropbox-api

i am using api-v2 for upload in dropbox. I am trying to upload images to dropbox using rest api by making ajax calls. I am able to upload but the images are not getting viewed in dropbox. What content of the image do i need to upload on dropbox (base64 or url of image)? And how should i pass the content of the file in ajax?

```
var data = JSON.stringify({"path":"/folder_name/" + i + ".jpg", "mode":{".tag":"add"}});
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: image,
                    processData: false,
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer access_token");
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Dropbox-API-Arg', data);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
                    },
                    success: function( response ) {
                        console.log("response" + response);
                    },
                    error : function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: What code have you written so far? You should be uploading the exact content (not encoded in any way) that you want to store.

Comment: @smarx : i tried sending base64, image URL.. i have uploaded the ajax call.

Comment: The above looks reasonable, depending on what `image` is.

Comment: Here the image means base64 string.

Comment: Well, don't base64 encode it. As I said, you should upload the exact (unencoded) bytes of the image.